# Unable to exit as destructor errors cause execution of main() to halt upon exit

Tags: c++

I have narrowed my problem down to passing 2 objects (which contain pointer data members) to a simple void function. The function returns clean, but when main() attempts to exit, it can not reclaim the first of the 2 objects. Here is a sample piece of code that shows the issue - along with print statements to show the address's of the objects as they are constructed, passed, and destructed.

If I only call "print1" - the program runs fine. However, if I call "printboth" - then the object "myNumbers" can not be freed. I can also make the error go away by removing the destructor statement:

```
 delete [] number;
```

but I don't think this is a good idea.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
class dummy
{
public:
    dummy() {
        number = new int[1];
        currentPos = -1;
        std::cout<<"default constructor called for "<<this<<std::endl;

    }
    dummy(int len) {
        number = new int[len];
        currentPos = -1;
        std::cout<<"parameterized constructor called for "<<this<<std::endl;

    }
    ~dummy() {
        cout<<"Calling destructor for "<<this<<endl;
        delete [] number;
    }
    int getNextNumber() {
        currentPos++;
        return number[currentPos];
    }
    void setNumbers(int position, int value) {
        number[position] = value;
    }
private:
    int* number;
    int currentPos;
};

void print1(dummy);
void printboth(dummy, dummy);

int main() {
dummy myNumbers(3);
myNumbers.setNumbers(0,0);
myNumbers.setNumbers(1,1);


dummy myOtherNumbers(3);
myOtherNumbers.setNumbers(0,4);
myOtherNumbers.setNumbers(1,5);

cout<<"Address of myNumbers is      "<<&myNumbers<<endl;
cout<<"Address of myOtherNumbers is "<<&myOtherNumbers<<endl;

print1(myNumbers);
printboth(myNumbers, myOtherNumbers);

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

void print1(dummy num) {
cout<<"Address of num is      "<<&num<<endl;
for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
    cout<<"Dummy number1 is "<<num.getNextNumber()<<endl;
return;
}
void printboth(dummy num1, dummy num2) {
cout<<"Address of num1 is      "<<&num1<<endl;
cout<<"Address of num2 is      "<<&num2<<endl;
for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
    cout<<"Dummy number1 is "<<num1.getNextNumber()<<endl;
    cout<<"Dummy number2 is "<<num2.getNextNumber()<<endl;
    }
return;
}
```

Comment: Your class doesn't follow the Rule of Three. Use RAII.

Comment: @chris, it would be helpful to explain the rule of three and RAII to someone that is clearly learning...

Comment: Well, the answer has the RoT link. Here's the RAII one: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6101039/Modern%20C++.pdf

Comment: Please **indent** your code properly.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum - this question is _too localised_ for a Q&A.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't follow [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

The problem is that when you call print1 or printboth the compiler calls the default copy-constructor (since you didn't provide one). That copy-constructor sets the number member variable of the copy to the same value as the original. When the destructor is called on the copy, the memory is released. Your original object now points to memory that has already been released so when its destructor is called, you crash(Nik Bougalis).

```
void print1(dummy);
void printboth(dummy, dummy);
```

You could pass dummy by const reference to avoid unnecessary copy, but strong recommand you follow [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

```
void print1(const dummy& );
void printboth(const dummy&, const dummy&);
```

Note:
You only created `size =1` array which is not necessary at all, just use `int number;` as member. If number holds dynamically allocated array, try use `std::vector<int>`.

getNextNumber is flawed, when it's called multiple times, `number[currentPos];` access boundry out of number which is undefined behavior.

```
int getNextNumber() {
        currentPos++;
        return number[currentPos];
    }
```

Which implies what suggested:

```
int getNextNumber() const {
      return number[currentPos];
   }
```

Comment: You should explain in a little more detail: the problem is that when you call `print1` or `printboth` the compiler calls the default copy-constructor (since you didn't provide one). That copy-constructor sets the `number` member variable of the copy to the *same* value as the original. When the destructor is called on the copy, the memory is released. Your *original* object now points to memory that has already been released so when its destructor is called, you crash. You can read more about the Rule of Three here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: Nik, you should post as an answer, now I steal yours and updated my answer.

Comment: These responses are helpful for sure. I will need clarification now on the assignment I am working on. The function prototype was given to me (it didn't use call-by-reference), I can't use "const" because inside the print function I call "getNext" - which updates a member variable currentPos. I will need to ask if I am allowed to add to the original code (which was provided) by adding in the copy constructor and copy assignment operators.

Comment: If you really need to update original object in `print purpose` function, remove `const` but that considered to be bad design.

Comment: @MichaelBoudreaux see my updated answer regarding getNextNumber()

Comment: @billz - yes, I see your point. I tried reducing code to make my point as much as possible. The getNextNumber as defined in my textbook does as I suggested above, but it will not allow the currentPos to be larger than the maximum index value. The reference code is the Sorted List ADT, from the book C++ Plus Data Structures (Nell Dale). I agree - the code I posted is useless, but it illustrates the issue I have during exit of main().

Comment: OK - The prof approved the use of the call-by-reference answer. Due to all of your feedback, I understand the rule of 3 now very well. Nik - I really appreciated your answer, it makes sense to me. However, why does "print1" work, but "printboth" doesn't?